# Is it possible to use vue-flipclock with Nativescript Vue app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to build my first Nativescript vue app based on/complimenting a previously existing web app. In that app I use the FlipClock.js.

I'd like to find a way to continue using this library for simplicity and consistency on the UI in my native app. There is a vue-flipclock component, but it still generates HTML which creates errors in the NativeScript app.

> CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:34096:14: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.5.17 | NSVue: 2.2.0)} -> CreateElement(div)'
>   ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****

Is there someway I can make this work inside the NativeSCript app, or do I need to find a different component altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use any plugin that depends on browser specific features / HTML DOM in NativeScript environment where your UI is totally native.

You might use a WebView if you want to load simple web app that might showcase the flipclock.

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach that was starting to make the most sense. I'll update my api to return the flipclock in a webpage and display in a webview. thanks.